# PowerCLI Get-VM filter out blank IP Address

Tags: powershell, powercli

I need to filter out the blanks in the "IP Address" column of the below PowerCLI script but am having a hard time figuring it out.

Here's the core script.

```
Get-VM | select Name, @{N="IP Address";E={@($_.guest.IPAddress[3])}}, Guest, PowerState
```

Here's one of the scripts I've tried and failed at.

```
Get-VM | select Name, @{N="IP Address";E={@($_.guest.IPAddress[3])}}, Guest, PowerState | where-object { @{N="IP Address";E={@($_.guest.IPAddress[3])}} -ne "" }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

-Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already made the customer property. You can now use it directly for filtering

```
Get-VM | select Name, @{N="IP Address";E={@($_.guest.IPAddress[3])}}, Guest, PowerState | where-object{$_."IP Address"}
```

or

```
Get-VM | Where-Object{$_.guest.IPAddress[3]} | select Name, @{N="IP Address";E={@($_.guest.IPAddress[3])}}, Guest, PowerState
```

If the property is null or empty the that will evaluate to false. In your example you were evaluating *the creation* of hash table. First example checks your newly created `IP Address` property. Second checks the source data for that property. Either way they *should* evaluate the same.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked a treat.  I knew it was probably something simple.  I can use your answer for other queries I'm working on as well.  Thanks again! -Rob